# Netcore server respond to slack interactive message

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, slack, slack-api

I am trying to build `Slack application` with asp net core server. Currently, I have added Slash command which makes a request to my local server through `ngrok`. Once my server receives that request, it makes a post request to configured `slack webhook` to display interactive message which looks like pic from attachment. [image]

I want user to be able to select yes or no and receive the result in my controller, but I can't realize how to tell Slack where should it make a post request. I attach the code of this message which is posted through `weebhook` into Slack:

```
{
"blocks": [
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "This is a section block with a button."
    }
    },
    {
        "type": "actions",
        "block_id": "actionblock789",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Yes"
                },
                "style": "primary",
                "value": "yes"
            },
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "No"
                },
                "value": "no"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

What I have in `netcore` is `TestController` with route `/api/test` which I suppose should receive from Slack a payload where information about selected button is set, but I couldn't find a way where specify a url in this json code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not configure a URL in the JSON code. That is not how it works with the Slack API.

Slack will send all responses to interactive message - like when someone clicks on a button - to the configured request URL of your Slack app. Check out this link how to find that parameter: [documentation](https://api.slack.com/messaging/interactivity/enabling#setting_up_interactions)

Comment: Oh, thank you. Slack documentation confused me. I couldn't figure out that I should set request url in Interactivity page since I didn't want to use custom actions